# Regex for number with or without extension

Tags: javascript, regex, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

How can I validate a number with or without the '+' extension using regex?.

I am using reactive forms Angular 2 and as I have it at the moment the validation is done when the '+' is included only. When I omit the '+' extension the validation fails

```
['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[+]{1}[0-9]+')]],
```

Comment: Add `?` after `[+]`

Comment: Use `?` quantifier: `\+?\d+`.

Comment: With this expression: `[+]{1}[0-9]+` you're saying that you're looking for: Exactly 1 "+"-sign, followed by at least 1, but a potentially infinite number of digits.

You can use `[+]?[0-9]+` to make the "+"-sign optional. Using `[+-]?[0-9]+` allows you to match anything that is `+number`, `-number`, or just `number` without any sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want [+] to be optional you can use

```
[+]{0,1}[0-9]+
```

or

```
[+]?[0-9]+
```